# SSL required error for twython API call

Tags: python, ssl, twitter, twython

I am trying to use twython to make API call for twitter and get the tweets. And I am receiving 403 error from twitter that says SSL is required. Can anyone help me how to finish this simply query?

Btw, I am using python 2.7. The OS is Windows 7.

```
from twython import Twython
tw = Twythonfrom twython import Twython(app_key=app_key,  app_secret=app_secret, oauth_token=oauth_token, oauth_token_secret=oauth_token_secret)
search = tw.search(q = 'Sandra')
for result in search:
    print result
```

And the error message

```
traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\local.admin\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\test\TwythonTest.py", line 33, in <module>
search = tw.search(q = 'Sandra')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twython\twython.py", line 133, in <lambda>
return lambda **kwargs: self._constructFunc(key, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twython\twython.py", line 149, in _constructFunc
content = self._request(url, method=fn['method'], params=kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twython\twython.py", line 218, in _request
retry_after=response.headers.get('retry-after'))
twython.twython.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), SSL is required
```